# Unable to commit to git with the gpg key error

Tags: git, gnupg, gpg-agent

Using `git version 2.20.1` and the official [guide](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.14/user/articles/generating-a-new-gpg-key), I ran the following commands to generate a pgp key

```
$ gpg --full-generate-key
...
$ gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
gpg: checking the trustdb
gpg: marginals needed: 3  completes needed: 1  trust model: pgp
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   1  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u
/home/mahmood/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
--------------------------------
sec   rsa4096/CFEFE6D58A392624 2020-09-08 [SC]
      26XX594XXXE2BAXXXE40AXXXCFXXX6D5XXXXX624
uid                 [ultimate] mahmood <EMAIL>
ssb   rsa4096/3B138A448B277FD9 2020-09-08 [E]
```

Now I can see the public key with this command:

```
$ gpg --armor --export CFEFE6D58A392624
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

mQINBF9XdKoBEACyQjVUlBYjOLSqv7YRIIq0+iJ9A0UzkItUoWBnDrHmTdnH+UeK
...
=WCOk
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

I then copied the key in the website according to this official [page](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.14/user/articles/adding-a-new-gpg-key-to-your-github-account).

[image]

Now when I want to commit, I get a key signing error:

```
$ git commit -S -m "...."
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

How can I fix that?

UPDATE:

Exporting the following variable will fix the problem.

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

How did I reach that? First I checked `~/.gitconfig` to be sure that `[user]` section is correct. Then I ran the following test command which gave me an ioctl error

```
$ echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

test
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Searching for that error led to `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` and then the test command was fine. Consequently the commit command is now OK.

Comment: `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` is what I needed! Thx.

Answer (score 8):

`man gpg-agent`,

```
         You should always add the following lines to your .bashrc  or  whatever
         initialization file is used for all shell invocations:

           GPG_TTY=$(tty)
           export GPG_TTY


         It is important that this environment variable always reflects the out-
         put of the tty command.  For W32 systems this option is not required.
```

From my using experience, environment variable `GPG_TTY` is needed by the `gpg-agent` to detect which tty/window/shell is active and **pop up a passphrase input prompt**.

You also need to update this info time by time. Otherwise the passphrase prompt may not pops up in your working shell, but another shell.

Most of the time, export `GPG_TTY` is enough. If you're using gpg-agent as a ssh agent as well. tty info is also need to be updated for gpg-agent's **ssh support**. Here is what I do for gpg-agent's ssh support in ZSH.

```
# Updates the gpg-agent TTY before every command since
# there's no way to detect this info in the ssh-agent protocol
function _gpg-agent-update-tty {
  gpg-connect-agent UPDATESTARTUPTTY /bye &>/dev/null
}

autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook preexec _gpg-agent-update-tty
```

Comment: For Bash, just add `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to .bashrc.

Comment: @jurez Yes, you're right. `GPG_TTY` is enough most of the time. The last zsh hook function is only for gpg-agent's **ssh support**.

Answer (score -1):

If you are still having problems in macOS, open `~/.gitconfig` and change everything under `[gpg]` to `program = /usr/local/bin/gpg`